# alert box make TemplateField label value disappear

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have `GridView` with `TemplateField` which contains a `Label`. The value of the `Label` is assigned in the code behind, everything works fine until the`alert box` shows up which makes the value of the `Label` disappear.

The `Label` code in `aspx`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="request number" SortExpression="req_id">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:Label ID="req_id" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The `alert box` in `aspx.cs`:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('Your Message');", true);
```

Comment: **What exactly is the problem?** You said that the `alert box` makes the `label`'s value disappear, but you aren't explaining much of the problem. Could you provide some more information?

Comment: the label value in the gridview disappear and it only show when I refresh the page

Comment: Could you post the full code for the **aspx**, and the **aspx.cs**? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: the issue doesnt happen when I use BoundField but I need to use TemplateField to control the label value cont

Comment: As I've said, I am lost at what you are saying.. I mean, I understand `BoundField` and `TemplateField`, I'll post an answer with some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "youralert", "alert('" + theString + "');", true);`

This will display an `alert` box in a sort of different way than your code does.

If you need more information, I am happy to help.